# How do I connect to signalR hub on another server and my client app on another server

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, signalr

I  have my signalR hub on another server, http://localhost:51109 and my client app on http://localhost:8100.
I know that placing the /signalr script in my html on my client server will result in a 404, how do I go about this. My client side is completely angular js.

Comment: Have you tried prepending the signalR hubs' URI before the '/signalr' part?

Comment: Try to allow CORS and add http://localhost:51109/signalr as source for the hub script. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the external script via the `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="http://localhost:51109/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Then in the Javascript code, utilize it like this:

```
$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:51109/signalr";
```

That's it.